# How to create new ElasticBeansTalk Application using JAVA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I need to create a new Elastic Beanstalk application and need to create an environment in it. How to do this using Java SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the below code and created an Application

```
AWSElasticBeanstalk client = AWSElasticBeanstalkClientBuilder.defaultClient();   
       CreateApplicationRequest request = new CreateApplicationRequest()
                        .withApplicationName("applicationName")
                        .withDescription("applicationDescription");
                CreateApplicationResult result = client.createApplication(createApplicationRequest);
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Following should be helpful. Please follow the steps

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html

Comment: I need to do this using JAVA SDK